# is it possible to copy entire foler to cab file in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How to add entire folder to cab file in WIX?
let I have a folder "images" located at path

```
   D:/Solutions/mywpfapp/images
```

This folder is used in my project, i want to use it.
if i want to use this entire folder in my installers cab file , what should i do?

we can copy the single file like

```
   <Component Id="icudtl.dat" Guid="ff624052-41ce-4ec8-970b-e1c19cf47fa7">
    <File Id="icudtl.dat" Name="icudtl.dat" Source="$(var.engage.client.app_TargetDir)icudtl.dat" />
  </Component>
```

I have heard something like

```
 harvest
```

But no idea how to use it, any one can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The WiX Harvest Tool, Heat, can be used to harvest a specified directory and generate WiX code for each file present:

```
heat.exe dir ".\HarvestDir" -ag -sfrag -out harvestout.wxs
```

See the Heat documentation [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) for more information.